# SQL encoding confusion

Tags: sql-server, character-encoding

I am a SQL newbie and I am a little confused with the encoding of SQL (SQL Server). Sometimes when I input data in Bulgarian language and save my script, later I get the not recognised encoding thing (like in HTML when you forget to put the encoding, but there it's easy, you just put the meta charset to utf8 and that's it). It seems that it's a little more complicated in SQL. Can someone please explain it to me?

Answer (score 0):

That's more like a Windows thing, should not be of any worries. When in Windows you save anything, including a .txt file it will ask you if it recognizes characters in other encodings to save it in it's corresponding encoding.

Does not really have to do with SQL

Comment: yea but still... first time when i worked with SQL Server I lost my data this way ... so I wonder if there is something simitar to the UTF8 in HTML so it recognises all language characters(german,chinese etc) not only english...

Comment: Yes, nvarchar vs varchar. nvarchar is unicode, which stores anything, varchar is dependent on column collation

Comment: and how should i change the encoding of the script that i save my sql code in?

Comment: If the file needs to be saved in a different encoding, SQL Management studio will prompt you after you hit save.

Comment: not rly ... on my pc i see it well but after i upload it to github... https://github.com/MitkoZ/test/blob/master/SQLQuery6.sql check the comments